# Why is ng-bind-html not displaying anything?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am displaying a string that has HTML code in it:

`<div style="font-size: 14px" ng-bind="currentBook.description"></div>`

put it displays the HTML code instead of interpreting the elements:

[image]

When I use `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-unsafe`, it shows nothing.

**How can I get the HTML to be parsed?**

## Addendum

I added a reference to sanitize but `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-unsafe` still show nothing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Ok, I added the ngSanitize `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);` and now it works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you missed **ngSanitize** please see demo below

You can find more here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.currentBook = {
    description: "<p>some description</p>"

  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <div style="font-size: 14px" ng-bind-html="currentBook.description"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks.Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

call apply

```
    $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.currentBook.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
        });
```