# ng-bind-html with $sce not rendering html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a string with both text and html from my Api and I want it to render both. Currently only the text is rendered. Here is my view and controller:

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('pakningInfohjelpModalController', pakningInfohjelpModalController); 

pakningInfohjelpModalController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal', 'content', '$sce' ]; 

function pakningInfohjelpModalController($uibModalInstance, $uibModall, content, $sce) {
    var ctrl = this; 

    ctrl.$onInit = () => {
        ctrl.title = content.modalTitle;
        content.modalBody = $sce.trustAsHtml(content.modalBody);
        if(content.modalBody == ''){
            ctrl.body = "Det finnes for øyeblikket ikke noen informasjon om dette feltet";
        }else{
            ctrl.body = content.modalBody.$$unwrapTrustedValue();
            console.log(ctrl.body);
        }
    }

    ctrl.lukk = () => {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Hjelp for {{$ctrl.title}}</h4>
        <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p><div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.body"></div></p>
                </div>
                <pre>
                    {{$ctrl.body}}
                </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-green pull-left" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.lukk()">Lukk</button>
    </div>
```

The console log in the controller logs both the text and the html. I have looked at several similar issues, but the solutions do not apply to my problem.

Resources:

[Why is ng-bind-html not displaying anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880658/why-is-ng-bind-html-not-displaying-anything)

The documentation is no help either:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Here is the string I want to bind:

```
                Fyllingsgraden skal indikere hvor godt innholdet i emballasjen opptar av emballasjens totale volum, basert på registrert bredde, dybde og høyde som ytre volum. <p><embed src="***" autostart="false"  width="100%" /></p>
```

The source is removed but its there in my code

Comment: can you reproduce your issue

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/hno8NpqdCjaP2zzdacoU/ i pasted the string in this plunkr example. the html is not rendering.

Comment: It would be good if your could make a [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) or a jsfiddle

Comment: see the link i provided in the comment above. When i paste the string I want to bind, I only get the text and not the html.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngSanitize`, inject it to the module.

Change the html code as following.

```
<pre>
     <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.body"></div>  
 </pre>
```

To know more about `ngSanitize` , check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Comment: It just shows the string and the html, nothing is rendered.

Comment: I have pasted the string in the demo of the link you provided. The html is still not rendered.